# Custom event in an observer

Tags: event-observer

Somebody suggested that I create a custom even within an observer to stop my first observer from holding up the event i.e. the event should occur whether or not the processes inside the observer have completed. It seems a strange idea. I don't know if it will work and could not find any thing on this method. Is there another way to free an event from its observer? Can they both go on simultaneously? I ask this knowing event observers are synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not parallel.

```
event1 thrown
observer1 run
    event2 thrown
    observer2 thrown
```

So, whatever you do, when the event is fired and the observer catched your event it runs.

The order is depending on the dependents of modules, but they NEVER run parallel.